# valgrind improper output location

Tags: c++, ubuntu, valgrind

I have a program that is supposed to run valgind on another program and direct the valgrind output to another file.  The code I'm using is:

```
char* args[] = {"sudo",  //(This is inside a fork)
        "valgrind",
        "--leak-check=full",
        "--show-leak-kinds=definite",
        "--errors-for-leak-kinds=definite",
        "<path to executable>", //placeholders
        "&><path to output file>", //placeholders
        "\0"};
execvp("sudo",args);
```

The problem I'm getting is that no matter what I do, it doesn't actually direct the output anywhere but the terminal.

I've tried "&>" and ">" with no change. I've tried running it in terminal with redirected output to file, I've also tried running it in eclipse with terminal arguments, etc.  I'm not sure what else I can try.

Does anyone have any idea why "&>" isn't redirecting?  I have confirmed that typing the args array in the terminal (not as part of the program) does work.  It seems to just be something with the c++ program (possibly fork?).

Comment: redirection is done by the shell not by `execvp`. Also check the man page for how arguments are ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [`--log-file=<filename>`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.basicopts) option.

From manual:

> `--log-file=<filename>`
>
> Specifies that Valgrind should send all of its messages to the specified file. If the file name is empty, it causes
> an abort. There are three special format specifiers that can be used
> in the file name.
>
> %p is replaced with the current process ID. This is very useful for
> program that invoke multiple processes. WARNING: If you use
> --trace-children=yes and your program invokes multiple processes OR your program forks without calling exec afterwards, and you don't use
> this specifier (or the %q specifier below), the Valgrind output from
> all those processes will go into one file, possibly jumbled up, and
> possibly incomplete.
>
> %q{FOO} is replaced with the contents of the environment variable FOO.
> If the {FOO} part is malformed, it causes an abort. This specifier is
> rarely needed, but very useful in certain circumstances (eg. when
> running MPI programs). The idea is that you specify a variable which
> will be set differently for each process in the job, for example
> BPROC_RANK or whatever is applicable in your MPI setup. If the named
> environment variable is not set, it causes an abort. Note that in some
> shells, the { and } characters may need to be escaped with a
> backslash.
>
> %% is replaced with %.
>
> If an % is followed by any other character, it causes an abort.
>
> If the file name specifies a relative file name, it is put in the
> program's initial working directory : this is the current directory
> when the program started its execution after the fork or after the
> exec. If it specifies an absolute file name (ie. starts with '/') then
> it is put there.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen that option when I'd looked at the help options.